# Use FullCalendar to create a weekly schedule

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am wondering if there is any way to use the FullCalendar to create a **weekly schedule** like the design below?

[image]

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Is it my imagination or did you ask this a few days ago, did you delete it since then? I think I already told you the suggestion: Use the timeGridWeek view and adjust the slot durations, and you can get pretty close to what you want. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timegrid-view and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotDuration

Comment: Thank you a lot ADyson. And yes I did ask this question again. I actually created an almost acceptable result yesterday thank to your previous answer and some of your other answers on StackOverFlow (man you are such a FullCalendar pro). I just re-ask this again to see if anyone will put some better code in the answer

Comment: If you found an acceptable solution you can  always answer it yourself. Then if anyone thinks of anything better they can add another one. Right now though we can't see your code so we don't know what "better" might look like.